# Sorting a text file by the second value

Tags: notepad++, notepad, emeditor

I was wondering if there is an option in notepad++ to sort a text file by the second value.

I have a txt that looks like this :

```
('sinon', 143)
('serais', 113)
('sens', 107)
('se', 323)
('sans', 113)
('sais', 702)
('sa', 137)
('s', 382)
('rien', 619)
('quoi', 611)
```

I tried to sort it by the value of the number and not alphabetically with notepad but no sucess so far. I also tried a bit of python but as I'm not really good at coding I didn't suceed here.

Comment: The better way is to use libreOffice Calc or Excell and sort by second column. Or write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: I tried to use excel but when i copy past it it but the thing in only one column, is it possible to paste it in 2 column ?

Comment: You have to remove `(`, `'`,`)` and spaces before. For example with Notepad++, Find: `[(') ]+` Replace:`Nothing`

Comment: I must be missing something, when I do what you say, every () is remplaced by a space and there is no ' anymore but when I copy paste that on excel it is still one column. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ can easily do the sorting. The method is to modify each line before doing the sort and then modify the lines again afterwards.

For this case just move everything before the number to the end of the line. Do a regular expression replace all changing `^(.*, )(\d.*)$` to `\2\1`. This changes the input text to be

```
143)('sinon', 
113)('serais', 
107)('sens', 
323)('se', 
113)('sans', 
702)('sais', 
137)('sa', 
382)('s', 
619)('rien', 
611)('quoi',
```

Then do the sort using menu => Edit => Line operations => Sort lines as integers ascending. Finally rewrite the lines in their original form. Do a regular expression replace all changing `$^(.*\))(.*)` to `\2\1`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know you can do this much with regular expression !

Comment: @Logrytoor See also [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60618065/546871) for ideas on more complex sorting needs.

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of EmEditor. If you EmEditor, you can switch to the CSV mode, select the second column, and select the "Sort Smallest to Largest" command.
[Sorting by column in EmEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJVbv.png)