# Sublime text 3 - how to order a list of exam marks (DESC / ASC)

Tags: text, notepad++, sublimetext3

Is there any way to order a huge list of Exam Marks?

for example:

```
firstname":"Chris", "lastname":"Malzahn"  , ..... Total Marks = 450 

firstname":"Zondra", "lastname":"Rideout" , ..... Total Marks = 157 

firstname":"Noemi", "lastname":"Gutierrez", ..... Total Marks = 489
```

i need result like

```
firstname":"Noemi", "lastname":"Gutierrez", ..... Total Marks = 489 

firstname":"Chris", "lastname":"Malzahn"  , ..... Total Marks = 450 

firstname":"Zondra", "lastname":"Rideout" , ..... Total Marks = 157
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting a text file by the second value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987307/sorting-a-text-file-by-the-second-value)

Comment: Just use different regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could import it into excel:

1. Open file in excel
2. Choose the Data tab atop the ribbon.
3. Select Text to Columns. (Use "=" as delimiter, so you get 2 columns, latter with the numer only)
4. Sort column