# How to sort a list with and without links alphabetic in Notepad++?

Tags: sorting, notepad++

I want to sort many lists alphabetic, but it doesn't work like I want, because some list items has a internal link and some items are not linked. Is it somehow possible to sort such lists, like I need it?

The output have to be in HTML code like my example list.

Here an example list:

```
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com/#ddd">ddd</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com/#bbb">bbb</a></li>
    <li>eee</li>
    <li>ccc</li>
```

This should be the output

```
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com/#bbb">bbb</a></li>
    <li>ccc</li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com/#ddd">ddd</a></li>
    <li>eee</li>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort lines after a certain character in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60613655/sort-lines-after-a-certain-character-in-notepad)

Comment: @AdrianHHH I don't think so.

Comment: Please explain why the answers there about how to sort lines with complex sort-keys does not apply to this question. Just saying *"I don't think so"* is not a real reason.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Could you please write here a similar answer for my sorting problem? I don't know, how to use the correct regular expression for this problem.

Comment: You might replace `^(<li>(?:<a [^<>\r\n]+>)?)(.*)$` with `$2!!!!$1`, then sort then replace `(.*)!!!!(.*)$` with `$2$1`.

Comment: Is it possible with Search and Replace to put the separator after the correct `>` after aaa,bbb,ccc .. of each line?

Comment: Your best option is to learn a little about regular expressions, then experiment starting with the two I provided.

Comment: I have found a solution, for my whitespace problem after added ^\s*. Feel free to post your great answer here.  Now I have too replace 3 times my lists, because in the end, I will add the whitespaces with `(\n|^)` to `\1    `

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ might not get you there, but with a little javascript you can re-arrange the list in a test-page and copy/paste it, or simply re-arrange in place.

Essentially, the code gets all the LI elements contained within a target container. It then passes them to a compare function. If the element contains a link the link's text is used, otherwise, the LIs text is what the comparison is based on.

Other string comparison exercises focus on `String.prototype.localeCompare`, though I've used what's reported as being higher in performance.

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

var strcmp = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {
  numeric: true,
  sensitivity: 'base'
}).compare;

function onLoaded(evt) {
  var items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li'));
  var sorted = items.sort(compTextContent);
  sorted.forEach(el => document.getElementById('output').appendChild(el.cloneNode(true)));
}

function compTextContent(a, b) {
  var linkA = a.querySelector('a');
  var linkB = b.querySelector('a');
  a = (linkA ? linkA : a);
  b = (linkB ? linkB : b);
  return strcmp(a.textContent, b.textContent);
}
```

```html
<div class='unsorted'>
  <li>aaa</li>
  <li><a href="https://example.com/#ddd">ddd</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://example.com/#bbb">bbb</a></li>
  <li>eee</li>
  <li>ccc</li>
</div>
<hr>
<div id='output'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Is it possible to get the output as HTML code like my example?

Comment: Really cool would be to put such a list in a textfield and with JQuery get instantly the output in HTML code.