# notepad++ or excel - delete duplicate ad original rows

Tags: duplicates, row, notepad++

I have a single .txt with +200k rows.
In this file, i want to delete duplicates and original rows.

I have now:

- text a
- text a
- text b
- text c
- text d
- text d
- text e

But i need a result like this

- text b
- text c
- text e

```
Suggest?


i have tried normal "delete duplicate" procedure of excel and notepad++ but i obtain this

text a
text b
text c
text d
text e

and it not work fine for me

looking for discussion i find something like that but applicated to access.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using Notepad++, do a regular expression replace of `^(.*\R)\1+` with nothing. Ensure that "**Wrap around**" is selected and that "**. matches newline**" is not selected. This assumes that the duplicate lines are grouped together; sorted lines would be ideal.

The regular expression is as follows

```
^                  Beginning of a line
(                  Start capture group
.*                 Zero or more of any character
\R                 An end of line
)                  End of capture group
\1+                One or more repeats of the capture group
```

If the last line of the file is part of a duplicated group but it does not have the end-of-line character(s) then the above regular expression will not find that last line. If the last three or more lines are identical, except that there is no final end-of-line character(s) then the above regular expression will remove most of the final group but leave one line. My recommendation is to ensure that the last line of the file has the end-of-line character(s) before using the regular expression. (Thanks to @Toto for pointing out this possible problem.)

Note that if the test for what is duplicated is more complex than exactly identical then the ideas in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60618065/546871) may be used.

Comment: It's better to put `\R` outside the group 1 because it doesn't match the last line if there is no linebreak. I'd use: `^(.+)\R(?:\1\R?)+`. Nevertheless you have my vote.

Comment: Thanks @Toto for pointing that out. I have added some more words about the issue. I could not see how to move the `\R` out of the group. Please consider the following extension of the question's example `\Rtext d\Rtext dtext d\Rtext d`.

Comment: The regex I have given [works fine](https://regex101.com/r/W2Bhpi/1). Or I didn't understand your comment?

Comment: @Toto the `\R?` means that the regex can match two captures without an intervening line break. Hence the `text dtext d` in my previous comment. See the bottome couple of lines in the test string of https://regex101.com/r/LH4uO3/1

Comment: Well, I see what you mean. Possible fix could be `^(.+)\R(?:\1$\R?)+` or `^(.+)\R(?:\1(?:\R|\z))+`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way how you can achieve it using python. Hope it helps :)

```
# Importing Pandas to create DataFrame
import pandas as pd

# Creating Empty DataFrame and Storing it in variable df
df = pd.DataFrame()

#replce this with our requiremnt
# lt = ["text a", "text a", "text b", "text c", "text d", "text d", "text e"]

text_file = open(r"C:\Users\antch\Desktop\txt.txt", "r")
lt = text_file.readlines()
# print (lt)
# print (type(lt))
text_file.close()

df['cols'] = lt
#creating an empty column with count value set to 1
df['dummy_count'] = 1

# grouping values 
df = df.groupby('cols').count()
# print(df)

df.reset_index(inplace = True)

df = df.loc[df["dummy_count"] == 1]
print(df["cols"])
```

the output of the above code: [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hii6O.png)

Comment: Thank you for reply.
but i have +200k.
I haven't 5 word.... so, in " lt = ["text a", "text a", "text b", "text c", "text d", "text d", "text e"]" how put inside to replace your example?

Comment: i edited the code now according to your requirement. hope it helps :)

Comment: They want a solution with Notepad++ or Excel, not python.

Comment: `df.to_excel("output.xlsx") ` adding this as the last line of the code will convert your data frame to excel. And that's your requirement.