# how to locally sort the lines in NP++

Tags: notepad++

Has any one met such a problem to sort in notepad++?

The text file contains the following lines

```
0.00000E+00    0.00000E+00    1    4.89402E-02
0.00000E+00    0.00000E+00    3    9.41098E+01
0.00000E+00    0.00000E+00    5    4.22547E+03
0.00000E+00    0.00000E+00    2    7.41087E-06
0.00000E+00    0.00000E+00    4    2.69642E-03
0.00000E+00    0.00000E+00    6    5.35888E-04
0.30000E+02    0.30000E+02    1    2.96322E-02
0.30000E+02    0.30000E+02    3    1.15594E+02
0.30000E+02    0.30000E+02    5    3.30169E+03
0.30000E+02    0.30000E+02    2    7.86962E-03
0.30000E+02    0.30000E+02    4    7.54210E+00
0.30000E+02    0.30000E+02    6    2.03730E+02
0.60000E+02    0.60000E+02    1    4.60685E-03
0.60000E+02    0.60000E+02    3    1.46504E+02
0.60000E+02    0.60000E+02    5    1.31320E+03
0.60000E+02    0.60000E+02    2    4.81953E-04
0.60000E+02    0.60000E+02    4    9.01484E+00
0.60000E+02    0.60000E+02    6    8.16669E+01
0.90000E+02    0.90000E+02    1    7.26858E-05
0.90000E+02    0.90000E+02    3    1.55457E+02
0.90000E+02    0.90000E+02    5    2.43385E+02
0.90000E+02    0.90000E+02    2    3.59327E-03
0.90000E+02    0.90000E+02    4    4.52146E-04
0.90000E+02    0.90000E+02    6    1.65717E-02
0.12000E+03    0.12000E+03    1    7.07527E-03
0.12000E+03    0.12000E+03    3    1.46518E+02
0.12000E+03    0.12000E+03    5    1.30634E+03
0.12000E+03    0.12000E+03    2    6.14906E-03
0.12000E+03    0.12000E+03    4    8.93463E+00
0.12000E+03    0.12000E+03    6    8.16950E+01
...
```

I need to sort the lines to locally 1~6 on 3rd column

```
0.00000E+00    0.00000E+00    1    4.89402E-02
0.00000E+00    0.00000E+00    2    7.41087E-06
0.00000E+00    0.00000E+00    3    9.41098E+01
0.00000E+00    0.00000E+00    4    2.69642E-03
0.00000E+00    0.00000E+00    5    4.22547E+03
0.00000E+00    0.00000E+00    6    5.35888E-04
0.30000E+02    0.30000E+02    1    2.96322E-02
0.30000E+02    0.30000E+02    2    7.86962E-03
0.30000E+02    0.30000E+02    3    1.15594E+02
0.30000E+02    0.30000E+02    4    7.54210E+00
0.30000E+02    0.30000E+02    5    3.30169E+03
0.30000E+02    0.30000E+02    6    2.03730E+02
...
```

I tried to find what:
^(( +\d.\d+E[+|-]\d+){2}) +1(( +-?\d.\d+E[+|-]\d+){1})\r\n^(( +\d.\d+E[+|-]\d+){2}) +3(( +-?\d.\d+E[+|-]\d+){1})\r\n
Replace with: \1    1\3\r\n....

But too many tags which I don't think working.

Comment: You can't natively do such sort in Notepad++. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language or use the `sort` command depending on your platform. Or use excel (or some similar)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort lines after a certain character in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60613655/sort-lines-after-a-certain-character-in-notepad)

Comment: @AdrianHHH, No! For sure I have searched that example before I posted mine. But that one is way too simple (3 tags are enough). That might be the reason someone misunderstood and down voted my question.

Comment: I upvoted to bring back to 0. Seems like a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has any one met such a problem to sort in notepad++

I have to admit: I have from time to time used Notepad++ for such tasks, when I was too lazy for writing an `awk`, `sed` or `python` script. If the task becomes a tiny bit more complicated then a real scripting language or spreadsheet is the only way.

But depending on how many lines you have (say a few thousand and not a million) this trick might be worth trying out in Notepad++:

1. do a Schwartzian transform, that is apply a regex that puts the
   sorting column at the start of each line:

   - Find What:  `(([0-9.]+E[-+][0-9]+[ ]+){2})([1-6])(.*)`
   - Replace with `\3 : \1\3\4`
2. go to first line, first char, record a macro:

   - Macro -> Start recording:
   - mark six lines: (hold down shift and while pressing Cursor Down six times)
   - select "Edit -> Line Operations -> Sort Lines as Integers Ascending
   - press Cursor Down one time (to unselect the six lines and go to the start of the next six line block)
   - Macro -> Stop recording
3. playback the macro **countless** times:

   - Press Ctrl-Shift-P and KEEP keys pressed to run over all lines in the file
   - this might sound silly and it will require that you hold the keys pressed for some time, but it will do what you require in a few seconds per thousand lines
4. undo the Schwartzian transform:

   - replace `[1-6] :`  with empty string

The trick is:

1. make the file a bit more suitable for the task by putting the sort field at the front
2. record a macro
3. apply the macro as long as necessary using the keyboard shortcut
4. undo step 1

And step one is needed so that we can use the sorting feature from the menu in the macro.

Comment: This seems a lot more complicated than the method in the suggested duplicate. Whilst the duplicate does not give the precise RegEx needed for this question, it gives the method and it does not use macros. I do not understand the reason for suggesting macros here. I have found that Notepad++'s sort works on quite big files.

Comment: @AdrianHHH The linked question is not a duplicate (as far as I understand the question here), the linked question has only one block that should be sorted.  

The macro part is used for the required "locality": that only blocks of six lines are sorted individually. Only a Schwartzian transform would sort all lines with "1" before all lines with "2".   
  
I understand the requirement of " need to sort the lines to locally 1~6 " that the first six lines should be sorted, then the next six lines should be sorted and so on.